# iOS- (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) before using Firebase Database.'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I was working on a project on xcode in swift and everything was okay with firebase, until I  got this error:  (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) before using Firebase Database.'  I'm guessing it happened after I added Auth.auth.currentuser. But the problem is not solved even after I removed the code Auth.auth().cutrent user. I tried replacing the GoogleServices.plist with a new one. But still no luck.

Comment: Did't get your problem. Can you please write your question in brief

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to ensure that your database isn't being initialized before using it. If you have the following in your initial view controller:

```
var ref =  Database.database().reference()
```

That can cause the error you're describing. Instead, you can use

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
```

and then assign a value when you actually use the reference, or use `lazy` so the variable isn't instantiated until the first time it's actually used.

```
lazy var ref = Database.database().ref()
```

If you're still experiencing the issue, I suggest you create a minimum reproducible code example and then update your question. Without showing any code, this is my best theory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import Firebase` into your `AppDelegate.swift` file, as well as add `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method; which is also inside your `AppDelegate.swift`.

Also, have you made sure that you're opening your `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj`

Comment: I already  did the notes you mentioned. This error came out of nowhere. Could it be an Xcode bug?